# Undefined relational operator for two objects of the same type - VHDL

Tags: operators, vhdl

I currently have a project in VHDL to make a simple vending machine. I have a `std_logic` signal to determine if the cash in is greater than or equal to the price of the item. The cost is an unsigned constant and the cash is an unsigned signal, but despite them both being unsigned numbers of equal bit length, it tells me the `>=` operator is undefined. I've looked in multiple reference guides, and all I can find is that the two arguments must be the same type (which they are...) so I'm not sure why it's throwing this error

I have included the proper `numeric_std` library.

```
type STATE_TYPE is (RDY, CLCT, VND);
signal state : STATE_TYPE;
signal next_state : STATE_TYPE;

signal cash : unsigned (7 downto 0);
signal cashnew : unsigned (7 downto 0);

signal candy : std_logic;
signal candy_vend : std_logic;
constant cost_candy : unsigned := to_unsigned(60, 8);

signal chips : std_logic;
signal chips_vend : std_logic;
constant cost_chips : unsigned := to_unsigned(50, 8);

begin

candy <= candy1 or candy2 or candy3;
chips <= chip1 or chip2;

candy_vend <= candy and (cash >= cost_candy);
chips_vend <= chips and (cash >= cost_chips);
```

Comment: It is not the `>=` operator that is undefined...e.g. `(cash >= cost_candy)` returns a `boolean`, while `candy` is a `std_logic`. There is no definition of an `and` operator that supports these two types together.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] next time.

Comment: Would the easiest way around this be to make another `std_logic` signal like `signal example : std_logic := (cash >= cost_candy)` or would it still have the same error since the operator returns a boolean?

Comment: `candy_vend <= '1' when candy = '1' and cash >= cost_candy else '0';` Note the relational operator is higher priority than the logical operator and candy = '1' evaluates to a Boolean too, where and is defined for Boolean operands. Besides a [mcve] please include the actual error message in the body of your question, it identifies the VHDL tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in other languages, VHDL has a `boolean` type. It is a integral type and provided in package `std.standard`. Thus this type is always visible, because this package is referenced by default.

Also like in other languages, a *relational* operator results in a boolean value. Neither the integral type `bit` nor the digital logic type `std_logic` is a boolean. Boolean has values `true` and `false`, where as bit has `0` and `1`. The `std_logic` type supports 9 values (9-valued logic, including e.g. error values).

Most operators are defined to accept the right and left operands of the same type, while returning that type again.

So you need to convert your expression at some point back to `std_logic`, because `candy_vend` is expecting that type.

**Solution 1:**

```
candy_vend <= candy and ('1' when (cash >= cost_candy) else '0');
```

**Solution 2:**

```
candy_vend <= '1' when ((candy = '1') and (cash >= cost_candy)) else '0';
```

**Solution 3:**

```
function to_sl(value : boolean) return std_logic is
begin
  if value then
    return '1';
  else
    return '0';
  end if;
 end function;
```

Usage:

```
 candy_vend <= candy and to_sl(cash >= cost_candy);
 candy_vend <= to_sl((candy = '1') and (cash >= cost_candy));
```

Comment: I didn't realize that `std_logic` could hold more than a `'0'` or a `'1'`, this helped me understand why I was getting the error.

Comment: If it solved your question, then please mark this answer as a solution :).