# How to use many "and" and "or" in one sentence in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl

I have this line of code:

`REn0 <= En0 and (conditionCode = "110" or conditionCode = "010");`

En0 is Std_logic  and condtionCode is Std_logic_vector of size 3 bits.

I am ORing whats inside the brackets and anding it with signal En0 but I get that weird error.

```
No feasible entries for infix operator 'and'.
Type error resolving infix expression "and" as type ieee.std_logic_1164.STD_LOGIC.
```

I don't understand these error messages. I can not do multiple or and and in vhdl ??

Comment: This example code is not complete. We need to know the types of all signals. I suspect you are mixing `std_logic` and `boolean` types.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undefined relational operator for two objects of the same type - VHDL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50090249/undefined-relational-operator-for-two-objects-of-the-same-type-vhdl)

Comment: EN0 is std_logic;  and conditionCode is Std_logic_vector (2 downto 0) @Paebbels

Comment: "and" is overloadable like other operators. There's one that takes two boolean arguments (for a boolean result)., one that takes 2 std_logics and returns a std_logic, and so on. Most likely the combination of argument and result types in your expression doesn't have a matching "and" operator declared for it.

Comment: is there an "and" that takes 2 std_logic_vectors ? @BrianDrummond

Comment: read the std_logic_1164 package and find out.

Comment: i understood the error ,when i read the std_logic_1164 package ..thank you @BrianDrummond

Comment: In addition to the question being a duplicate, it does not present a [mcve].

Comment: definitly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50090249/undefined-relational-operator-for-two-objects-of-the-same-type-vhdl

Comment: @JHBonarius This is the same link as my duplicate link.

Comment: @Paebbels I know. I just want to back you up. Cannot vote yet

Comment: @JHBonarius Oh, I didn't notice that :).

Comment: @user1155120 i know i should have added the size/type of each signal but i thought it would not be helpful ..anyway my apologies and i did fix the bug..many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it..the error was because i was Anding a signal(1 bit) with a vector of bits..where no function in the std_logic_1164 package does that.

a simple soultion is:

```
x  <= '1' when  conditionCode = "110" else '0';
y  <= '1' when   conditionCode = "010" else '0';
REn0 <= En0 and ( x or y);
```

Comment: `the error was because i was Anding a signal(1 bit) with a vector of bits.` No, you were AND'ing a Boolean expression result `(conditionCode = "110" or conditionCode = "010")` with a standard_logic vector (and there's no operator overload for doing so). You don't show the declarations for  x and y, context clause nor which version of VHDL while appearing to depend on the logical reduction operator "and"[std_ulogic_vector, std_ulogic return std_ulogic_vector] (found in the -2008 package std_logic_1164).

Comment: Or you could have done `REn0 <= '1' when En0 = '1' and (conditionCode = "110" or conditionCode = "010") else '0';`

Comment: @user1155120   You are right ,i was anding Boolean expression ,and no operator overload for that ...and x and y are just 1 bit signals..i didn't add them because it was obvious to tell..however the solution i provided has solved the case Thank you :) .

Comment: you are ORing a Boolean expression result..it's the same as i did first time(the one that got an error)  @JHBonarius

Comment: @Abdel-RahmanEl-Feraly yes, you noticed correctly. But I am not or-ing a boolean with a `std_logic`, like you did. I am or-ing booleans with other booleans, which is perfectly OK. I am using the result (again a boolean) to select `'1'` if true or `'0'` if false. Just check the code. It works. No errors.